# How to create a dotplot of two DNA sequence in python

Tags: python-2.7

I am interested to do a  dot plot matrix of two dna sequences with k as identity similarity score, and t as a threshold. I am learning python and although I am good with data I struggle with tables, and dotplots. I created the above code to produce a simple identity matrix. Now I need to change it or produce a new one.

See [this paper](http://www.cs.unibo.it/~dilena/LabBII/LabBI-I.pdf) for needed definitions.

Comment: I have added the code I used before to create a simple dot plot matrix. I would like to know if i could change something on it so the asterisc are only present at a certain threshold.

Comment: I have just added but I have issues with the posting as you can see not all gets in the form of code. I tried several times. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: The .py script I have worked so hopefully the copy and paste has to damage it. That script produced a plot where asterisc are showing the matching amino acids. What I would like to do is to produce a similar code or a similar plot of seq1, seq2, k, t (as threshold). Something similar to  slide 4 in http://www.cs.unibo.it/~dilena/LabBII/LabBI-I.pdf. I hope I have explain better what I would like to do. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: I have modified my query, and I think that now it is much clear. I hope so.

Comment: you can check how we generate dotplots (including stringency and similarity matrices) in a [dotplot mini-tool](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dotplot/0.4.5) (disclaimer: I am one of the authors).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should separate the logic of generating the matrix from the comparatively easy logic of making a character plot of it.

First define the delta function:

```
def delta(x,y):
    return 0 if x == y else 1
```

Now `M[i,j]`:

```
def M(seq1,seq2,i,j,k):
    return sum(delta(x,y) for x,y in zip(seq1[i:i+k],seq2[j:j+k]))
```

Make a matrix of this:

```
def makeMatrix(seq1,seq2,k):
    n = len(seq1)
    m = len(seq2)
    return [[M(seq1,seq2,i,j,k) for j in xrange(m-k+1)] for i in xrange(n-k+1)]
```

Plot a matrix. You can experiment with different characters:

```
def plotMatrix(M,t, seq1, seq2, nonblank = unichr(0x25A0), blank = ' '):
    print(' |' + seq2)
    print('-'*(2 + len(seq2)))
    for label,row in zip(seq1,M):
        line = ''.join(nonblank if s < t else blank for s in row)
        print(label + '|' + line)
```

A wrapper function:

```
def dotplot(seq1,seq2,k = 1,t = 1):
    M = makeMatrix(seq1,seq2,k)
    plotMatrix(M, t, seq1,seq2) #experiment with character choice
```

And then:

```
#for testing purposes (drawn from paper):

seqx = "ACCTGAGCTCACCTGAGTTA"
seqy = "ACCTGAGCTCACCTGAGTTA"
dotplot(seqx,seqy)
```

Output:

```
 |ACCTGAGCTCACCTGAGTTA
----------------------
A|■    ■    ■    ■   ■
C| ■■    ■ ■ ■■       
C| ■■    ■ ■ ■■       
T|   ■    ■    ■   ■■ 
G|    ■ ■       ■ ■   
A|■    ■    ■    ■   ■
G|    ■ ■       ■ ■   
C| ■■    ■ ■ ■■       
T|   ■    ■    ■   ■■ 
C| ■■    ■ ■ ■■       
A|■    ■    ■    ■   ■
C| ■■    ■ ■ ■■       
C| ■■    ■ ■ ■■       
T|   ■    ■    ■   ■■ 
G|    ■ ■       ■ ■   
A|■    ■    ■    ■   ■
G|    ■ ■       ■ ■   
T|   ■    ■    ■   ■■ 
T|   ■    ■    ■   ■■ 
A|■    ■    ■    ■   ■
```

Which matches the figure from the paper (although it lacks the row and column labels -- which you could add-in if desired):

[image]

Comment: Wow! I'm impressed I will check the code, and tested, and change some parameter to know what happens. Also, could you recommend me some reading in the subject graphs in python but not matlabplot.Thank you very much. I will tried to include headers too.

Comment: The Book "Bioinformatics Programming using Python" by Mitchell Model has a chapter on making dotplots using the graphics library Tkinter. It is in Python 3 but should (with a few modifications) work with Python 2. Something like matlabplot is much richer than what you can do with raw Tkinter, so I am not sure why you would want to avoid that. There are a number of books with titles like "Data Visualization in Python" that could get you started.

Comment: Hi, I am trying to work out how to insert the headings, any help there, please?

Comment: See edit. You can tweak the row/column delimiters such as `'|'` and `'-'` or eliminate them all together. You can also mark answers as accepted on Stack Overflow if you feel that they answer your question.

Comment: Note for python3 users to swap out `xrange` with `range` and `unichar` with `char`

Answer (score 4):

Minor addition to the accepted answer here to get a prettier plot...

```
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
dotplot=plt.imshow(numpy.array(makeMatrix(seqx,seqy,1)))
xt=plt.xticks(numpy.arange(len(list(seqx))),list(seqx))
yt=plt.yticks(numpy.arange(len(list(seqx))),list(seqx))
plt.show()
```

[image: example dot plot]